# SSIS Task "Execute SQL" is not in my toolbox. How can I get it?

Tags: ssis

I see several examples that show how to use the Execute SQL task.  One such example I see this screen shot:

[image: Extra Tasks]

There are a lot of tasks there that I don't have in my task list.  The one I am looking for is "Execute SQL".

I also note that they don't have "OLE DB Command" (which is what I would usually use to call SQL).

Do I just have a different version?  Is "OLE DB Command" the successor to "Execute SQL"?  Or is there some way to get the stuff I am missing?

Comment: can you post up a picture of what you actually have in the Toolbox

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might be inside a Data Flow - that will only show you items related to a Data Flow (Data Flow Sources, Data Flow Transformations, Data Flow Destinations).

If you are in the Control Flow, and cannot see the items you indicate as missing, you can right click to add.

[image]

This will give you a dialog box where you can choose the items that you want to add

[image]

Comment: That was it.  thanks!  (Though I don't get the point of Execute SQL at that level)

Comment: The Execute SQL at the Control flow is meant to execute a stand=alone command, or to get back a recordset that you can loop through in the For-Each loop (among other things)

Answer (score 6):

In SQL 2012 / VS 2010, the `Execute SQL Task` only appears in the `Favorites` bar at the top. This is confusing - why is it *only* a favourite?

[image]

You can however right-click and "move" to `Common`, but not "copy" to `Common`:

[image]

Comment: You have to click on "Control Flow" in the SSIS Design screen near the top, in order to see "Execute SQL Task" in the SSIS Toolbox. This also works in Visual Studio 2019 with the "SQL Server Integration Services Projects" extension added.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue in VS 2010 and VS 2012.  To fix it, here's what I had to do:

1. Exit Visual Studio
2. Navigate to %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio
3. Go to the folder for your version (e.g. 11.0 for VS 2012)
4. Rename all *.tbd files, e.g. to *.tbd.old
5. Open visual studio
6. Open toolbox by going to View > Other Windows > SSIS Toolbox

Similar problem here:
http://geekswithblogs.net/AskPaula/archive/2013/07/11/153385.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I had this in VS 2022 and the reason was, Deployment Target Server Version was set to 2017.

The minute I changed it to 2022, I got all the items in the toolbox.

Right Click SSIS Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> General